# reading text as a dataframe into R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, csv, tidyverse

In my `DATA` below, `read.table()` requires `study` column to not have any white spaces between its elements. For example, if an element is `"Hayati & Jalilifar"`, then `read.table()` throws an error until the user deletes the white spaces like `"Hayati&Jalilifar"`.

But is there a way for `read.table()` to read the `DATA` below without needing to delete the white spaces between any data elements as is?

```
DATA = read.table(header=TRUE, text = 
 "study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277")
```

Comment: Is this an output from a package in R?  If so, you may be able to assign it to variable as a dataframe and access the table that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your text in a variable and use the following:

```
 read.table(text=gsub("(\\S+\\s+[&]\\s+\\S+)", "'\\1'", txt), header = TRUE)
               study year      g    v_g assign_type n_class  Nt  Nc
1 Hayati & Jalilifar 2009  0.213 0.1010     student      NA  20  20
2 Hayati & Jalilifar 2009  0.785 0.1080     student      NA  20  20
3    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.894 0.0154       class       4 286 286
4    Hale & Courtney 1994  0.946 0.0156       class       4 286 286
5    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.237 0.0146       class       4 277 277
6    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.179 0.0146       class       4 277 277
```

---

```
txt <- "study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277"
```

Comment: Really nice and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your data is in fixed width format. Based on your example data here is an approach using `readr::read_fwf` which works almost perfect except that it splits the first column into two. Additionally it needs a second step to get the column names:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

tmp <- tempfile()

writeLines(
  text = "study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277",
  tmp
)

dat <- readr::read_fwf(
  file = tmp, skip = 1
) |>
  mutate(X1 = paste(X1, X2), .keep = "unused")


names(dat) <- readr::read_table(tmp, n_max = 0) |> names()

dat
#> # A tibble: 6 × 8
#>   study               year      g    v_g assign_type n_class    Nt    Nc
#>   <chr>              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student          NA    20    20
#> 2 Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student          NA    20    20
#> 3 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class             4   286   286
#> 4 Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class             4   286   286
#> 5 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class             4   277   277
#> 6 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class             4   277   277
```

Answer (score 1):

A kind of workaround in `base-R` I sometimes use:

```
txt <- "study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277"

data <- read.table(text = txt, header = FALSE, skip = 1L)
data$V1 <- with(data, paste(V1, V2, V3))
data[, c("V2", "V3")] <- list(NULL)
colnames(data) <- read.table(text = txt, nrows = 1L)
```

gives

```
> head(data)
               study year      g    v_g assign_type n_class  Nt  Nc
1 Hayati & Jalilifar 2009  0.213 0.1010     student      NA  20  20
2 Hayati & Jalilifar 2009  0.785 0.1080     student      NA  20  20
3    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.894 0.0154       class       4 286 286
4    Hale & Courtney 1994  0.946 0.0156       class       4 286 286
5    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.237 0.0146       class       4 277 277
6    Hale & Courtney 1994 -0.179 0.0146       class       4 277 277
```

Answer (score 1):

The `read.table()` function has two useful arguments for reading such kind of data where there are lots of spaces and ...: These are `strip.white=` and `sep="\t"`. In your case the first should be set to `TRUE`. To prevent any automatic convertion from base R you could also add the argument `check.names=F`. That's all you need to do:

```
DATA = read.table(header=TRUE, check.names = F, strip.white = T, sep = "\t", text = 
                      "study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
  Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277")
```

So you must get no ERROR and here is the DATA output as you may looking for:

```
DATA
   study               year  g     v_g    assign_type  n_class Nt    Nc
1  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.213 0.101  student      NA      20    20
2  Hayati & Jalilifar  2009  0.785 0.108  student      NA      20    20
3 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.894 0.0154 class        4       286   286
4 Hale & Courtney     1994  0.946 0.0156 class        4       286   286
5 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.237 0.0146 class        4       277   277
6 Hale & Courtney     1994 -0.179 0.0146 class        4       277   277
```